# Win32DiskImager working with compressed files

Tags: sd-card, windows, image, win32diskimager

Win32DiskImager is a cool tool on Windows except:

- we have to manually extract the ZIP file and then flash it, and then delete the ZIP
- it doesn't seem to work in command-line

Is there a way to make it work with compressed files? like:

```
win32diskimager image.img.zip e:\
```

Note: linked feature request: https://sourceforge.net/p/win32diskimager/features/3/

Comment: Use etcher https://etcher.io

Comment: @CoderMike Looks cool, this seems to be a solution (feel free to post as answer)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Etcher - i've found it more reliable than Win32DiskImager and it will write an image direct from a compressed image.

https://etcher.io

Comment: What is the correct way to compress an image for Etcher?  (Compressing to a zip file with Windows 10 causes Etcher to complain and fail.  Um, or I did something wrong.)

Comment: @BobBrown Take an .iso or .img, compress it with ZIP (it will be a zipped IMG) e.g. `myimage.img.zip`. Then Etcher seems to accept it. Pros: you don't need to uncompress 400 MB zipped images to 3 GB file before flashing.

Comment: @Basj  Thank you.  Based on your comment, I've used gzip to reduce a 15 GB image to 3 GB and then flash to SD card.  (I'm now going to have to look into making smaller images because even the compressed file takes 40 minutes to flash.)